# SLiM not working in Arch Linux with Gnome

Tags: arch-linux, display-manager, slim

I'm trying to change my login manager to [SLiM](http://slim.berlios.de/index.php) and the theme I want for my login screen is archlinux-simplyblack:

```
[cesar@arch ~]$ ls -la /usr/share/slim/themes/
total 108
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 May  9 19:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  8 11:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 23  2008 archlinux-darch-grey
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 23  2008 archlinux-darch-white
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 23  2008 archlinux-retro
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 23  2008 archlinux-simplyblack
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov 23  2008 archlinux-soft-grey
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 capernoited
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 debian-moreblue
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  8 11:11 default
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 fingerprint
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 flat
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 flower2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 isolated
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 lake
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 lotus-midnight
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 lotus-sage
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 lunar
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 mindlock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 parallel-dimensions
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 previous
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 rainbow
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 rear-window
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 scotland-road
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 subway
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 wave
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 25 04:16 zenwalk
```

In order to run SLiM at boot time I edited my `/etc/rc.conf` an added slim to `DAEMONS` (I haven't changed my `/etc/inittab`):

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng dbus hal networkmanager net-profiles net-auto-wireless crond alsa gdm slim)
```

I created the `~/.initrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec gnome-session
```

And also make `~/.initrc` executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 cesar users   30 May  9 00:22 .xinitrc
```

This is the what `/var/log/slim.log` shows:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 


Giving up.
slim: unable to connect to X server
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /var/run/slim.auth does not exist


Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 

Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyGiving up.
slim: unable to connect to X server
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT: /etc/slim.conf**

```
# Path, X server and arguments (if needed)
# Note: -xauth $authfile is automatically appended
default_path        /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
default_xserver     /usr/bin/X
xserver_arguments -nolisten tcp vt07

# Commands for halt, login, etc.
halt_cmd            /sbin/shutdown -h now
reboot_cmd          /sbin/shutdown -r now
console_cmd         /usr/bin/xterm -C -fg white -bg black +sb -T "Console login" -e /bin/sh -c "/bin/cat /etc/issue; exec /bin/login"
#suspend_cmd        /usr/sbin/suspend

# Full path to the xauth binary
xauth_path         /usr/bin/xauth 

# Xauth file for server
authfile           /var/run/slim.auth


# Activate numlock when slim starts. Valid values: on|off
numlock             on

# Hide the mouse cursor (note: does not work with some WMs).
# Valid values: true|false
hidecursor          false

# This command is executed after a succesful login.
# you can place the %session and %theme variables
# to handle launching of specific commands in .xinitrc
# depending of chosen session and slim theme
#
# NOTE: if your system does not have bash you need
# to adjust the command according to your preferred shell,
# i.e. for freebsd use:
# login_cmd           exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session

# Commands executed when starting and exiting a session.
# They can be used for registering a X11 session with
# sessreg. You can use the %user variable
#
# sessionstart_cmd  some command
# sessionstop_cmd   some command

# Start in daemon mode. Valid values: yes | no
# Note that this can be overriden by the command line
# options "-d" and "-nodaemon"
# daemon    yes

# Available sessions (first one is the default).
# The current chosen session name is replaced in the login_cmd
# above, so your login command can handle different sessions.
# see the xinitrc.sample file shipped with slim sources
sessions            gnome-session

# Executed when pressing F11 (requires imagemagick)
screenshot_cmd      import -window root /slim.png

# welcome message. Available variables: %host, %domain
welcome_msg         Welcome to %host

# Session message. Prepended to the session name when pressing F1
# session_msg         Session: 

# shutdown / reboot messages
shutdown_msg       The system is halting...
reboot_msg         The system is rebooting...

# default user, leave blank or remove this line
# for avoid pre-loading the username.
#default_user        simone

# Focus the password field on start when default_user is set
# Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#focus_password      no

# Automatically login the default user (without entering
# the password. Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#auto_login          no


# current theme, use comma separated list to specify a set to 
# randomly choose from
current_theme       archlinux-simplyblack

# Lock file
lockfile            /var/lock/slim.lock

# Log file
logfile             /var/log/slim.log
```

Comment: Also, `hal` was deprecated some time ago...

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: I believe the replacement is `udev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `DAEMONS` list you posted you have both `gdm` and `slim`.  I don't think you can run both on the same display, and you probably don't want `gdm` anyways so just remove it from the list.